# Unsupported version error using JTDS with Scala

Tags: java, scala, jtds, spray

I'm trying to use the Java JTDS driver to connect to my database in Scala . However, whenever I try to use it I get an error that the version(of java?) is wrong.

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbcx/JtdsDataSource : Unsupported major.minor
>   version 51.0

```
object DaoDriverAdaptor {
  import java.sql.{DriverManager, Connection}

  private def loadDriver() {
    try {
      Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource")
    } catch {
      case e: Exception  => {
        println("ERROR: Driver not available: " + e.getMessage)
        throw e
      }
    }
  }
```

- Scala version : 2.9.2
- Java Version : 1.6
- Using jtds 1.3.0
- Output of java -version:

java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10-428-11M3811)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01-428, mixed mode)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, your Java runtime is too old, according to [Java class file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file):

- J2SE 7 = **51** (0x33 hex),
- J2SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),
- J2SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex),
- JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex),
- JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex),
- JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex),
- JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex).

51.0 means you need Java 7 to run some of the classes in your project. And you are right it's jTDS that's causing the problem (from [*jTDS JDBC Driver 1.2.7 and 1.3.0 released*](http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/news/2012/10/jtds-jdbc-driver-127-and-130-released/)):

> Version 1.3.0 is the first Java 7 compatible version of the driver and

Either upgrade to Java 7 (always a good idea) or downgrade to some older jTDS driver.

Comment: Scala still isn't 100% compatible with JDK7, so I'll stick to the older driver for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

From the [release notes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.0/release%20notes.txt/download):

> *You should only stick to the jTDS 1.2.x line of the driver if you require to use
>   Java versions prior to Java 7.*